# uint f = 0, f *= computationallyHeavyFunction(), does EVM run computationallyHeavyFunction()?

Tags: evm

```
uint f = 0;
f *= computationallyHeavyFunction();
```

Does EVM run `computationallyHeavyFunction()`, or does it evaluate f = 0 and then omit further computation?

Answer (score 1):

It runs it.

The first line casts `f` as `uint`. `=0` is pointess because it defaults to `0`.

The second line invokes a function and assigns the response to `f`.

It would also be okay to:

`uint f = 0 * computationallyHeavyFunction();`

Of course, `f` is `0` in any case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: was just wondering if it paid the gas for it or not, since the EVM would, once it sees "f = 0" know that the result of computationallyHeavyFunction() would not matter

Comment: could I also ask, is it standard for VMs to run *= if the left hand side is 0?

Comment: Q1: I don't think so, but you could have "computationallyHeavy" emit an event to be sure. Q2: The previous assignment is unimportant. I thought the `0 *` phrasing looked a little weird, but it might be a way to silence warnings about ignoring a returned value. Otherwise, the function could be invoked without `f` existing at all and it would be cheaper. Maybe there should be no returned value if callers just ignore it/it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it does run it.  First point, though, is that this is a property of the Solidity compiler, not the EVM itself - it could, if it thought it was correct, just not generate the EVM bytecode, so it wouldn't be run.

However, there is an issue of side-effects.  The *result* of `computationallyHeavyFunction()` might not matter, but the function could modify storage or generate an exception.  Consider this code:

```
contract optimisationTest{

    bool public flag;
    uint public foo;

    function setFlag() internal returns (uint256) {
        flag = true;

        return 1;
    }

    function complexCode() internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 j;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
            j += i;
        }

        return j;
    }

    function test() public {
        foo = 0 * setFlag();
        foo = 0 * complexCode();
    }
}
```

Unless it's specifically mentioned in the language definition that right-hand-side functions aren't called in this case, then it's down to the optimiser to work it out using static analysis or similar.

I compiled this with optimisations on.  Both `setFlag()` and `complexCode()` are called in Solidity 5.11 - I checked the latter with the debugger.  The second one could indeed be eliminated in the optimiser but this does not appear to be the case with Solidity today.